# Special characters not being replaced with regex

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm trying to filter some special characters from a string and I'm using the below code and regex conditions.

I was expecting it to filter out everything excep `-`, `+` and `#` but there are a few more characters not being filtered.

```
text = "This is a long string~!@#$%^&*()_+|\=-{}[];':<>?with special characters"

print sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9 -+#]+', '', text)
```

And the result which is being displayed is:

```
This is a long string!#$%&*()+'with special characters
```

What I'm expected to be printed out is:

```
This is a long string with #+- special characters
```

Can anyone please explain why this is happening and how I can correct my regex or code to filter out the remaining characters?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Sorry, I took out a little few more things from my expected output than I meant to.

Comment: You will not get space after between `with` and `#+-` as original string doesn't have space at that place

Comment: @anubhava I have already corrected that in my `text string`. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must not use an **unescaped hyphen in the middle of character class**, use:

```
print re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9 +#-]+', '', text)
```

Comment: Also, reordering the last 3 characters to `#+-` in the `regex` condition will work. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could do like this also.

```
>>> re.sub(r'(?![#+ -])[_\W]', '', text)
'This is a long string#+-with special characters'
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `str.translate`:

```
text = "This is a long string~!@#$%^&*()_+|\=-{}[];':<>?"

# string.punctuation - +-#
rem ="""!"$%&'()*,./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~"""

print(text.translate(None,rem)))
This is a long string#+-
```

translate is a lot more efficient when you just want to remove characters:

```
In [28]: r  = re.compile(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9 +#-]+')    
In [29]: timeit text.translate(None,rem)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 408 ns per loop   

In [30]: timeit r.sub("", text)
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.66 µs per loop  

In [31]: r.sub("", text)
Out[31]: 'This is a long string#+-'    
In [32]: text.translate(None,rem)
Out[32]: 'This is a long string#+-'
```

Comment: This will remove the `-`, `+`, and `#`.

Comment: @abarnert, them simply remove them from punctuation